# Photo and video recovery

Tags: sync, photos

I accidentally deleted an entire timeline of photos off of gallery. My phone was set to sync with my Gmail account and Facebook. Where do I find these synced photos and videos through my Gmail or Facebook? Some of the photos were really important for work.

Comment: Did you try in google plus ??

Answer (score 0):

Sync propagates deletion as well, therefore if you deleted your photos on the source, they will most likely be deleted from synced locations as well.

You can still recover some pictures from your device provided some conditions are met: you did **not** use your phone extensively (i.e. you did not use the storage anyhow) after the deletion **and** your phone is already rooted or you have at least custom recovery. Via `root shell` or `adb shell` or custom recovery adb shell do a `dd` backup of data partition to a file on an external sdcard and then run `photorec` software on the file. Or, if your phone supports usb mass storage, do a `dd` backup of that mass storage block device - that's the same as data partition. If you do not have an external sdcard, you'd have to do the image via some netcat magic, which is too complicated to be described under this question - ask another one on this topic and I'd be more than happy to elaborate.

Details of this approach are model-specific (save for the usb mass storage option) therefore it wouldn't make much sense to describe it here in detail.